# Workaround for FSCK "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTANCY; Run fsck manually

Tags: linux

I have a Linux System based LFS (Linux from Scrach). Linux kernel version 2.6.29.6 #1 SMP PREEMPT. This system uses Extlinux bootloader and boots from SSD (Micron USB Solid State Device). There is also a seconday harddrive in this system but not meant for booting. We changed the booting from HDD to SSD as we found SSD is fast and reliable over HDD.

Whenever there is a power outage, the unit reboots, the power Outage causes the SSD corruption. After reboot, the Fsck command is run by the script checkfs. The system halts with the Error message ""UNEXPECTED INCONSISTANCY; Run fsck manually error and unit halts and fails to reboot until we manually reboot.

I checked the checkfs script and found that, in this condition, the fsck -a -A -C -T is run and returns error value > 3 and < 16 for which the action is to halt the system and reboot using CD and run fsck manually and fix the issue.

I tried changing the checkfs script and used fsck -y which fixed all the errors and the unit booted normally but while fixing the issues, many files were deleted. Secondly if i ignore the fsck error and instead of system halt, if i go ahead with normal boot, it works but since it doesnt fix the filesystem issues, the unit may not work properly.

At this point i would like to know if there are any work arounds to resolve this issue and still boot the system normally and fix the filesystem issues? can i do something like if fsck fails then umount root file system from SSD and mount it from HDD and boot normally, then after boot recover SSD filesystem? if yes any pointers to do this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can append 'fastboot' as a kernel argument (in grub) to skip fsck.